# Matplotlib : How to plot two bar plots with the same x/y axes but one start over the other along y axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot two bar plots int the same figure. In the code below the plots are one behind the other because they laid along y axis at 0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x1=np.array([1,2,3,2,1])

x2=np.array([1,2,3,2,1])
y2=np.array([6,7,8,9,10])
plt.bar(y1,x1)
plt.bar(y2,x2)
```

[image]

I would the orange bar plot starts from coordinates: (x=6, y=3). So orange bar plot should be over the blue  plot and in the same figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide the value of the bottom for the second bar plot using `bottom=3`

```
plt.bar(y2,x2, bottom=3)
```

You can also make it more general using `bottom=max(x2)`

[image]

**For horizontal bar chart** Use `left=3`

```
plt.barh(y2,x2,left=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Take care!